# PyQt QMediaPlayer Framing Forward With Some (Not All) Video Files

Tags: python, pyqt, frame, smoothing, qmediaplayer

I’m having an issue with video frame-by-frame movement in a custom video player I created using PyQt QMediaPlayer on a Wndows platform.  I want the video to advance one frame frame forward or backward and then pause whenever I click a button.

Videos can come from various camcorders, including SD, HD, and 4K.  Some of the videos frame forward or backward without any issue.  However, I have videos from two different camcorders where the video stutters when framing forward or backward.  Video files from one camera have a file extension of .MOD and the other has a file extension of .MTS.  These videos remain paused when framing forward or backward for 14-16 frames and then the video jumps to the current frame, which I assume is a key frame.

The getMetaData method in my instance of QMediaPlayer and VLC Codec information provide slightly different values for the codecs in these two videos.  Herename are the codecsvalues from both:

| File Extension | QMediaPlayer | VLC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .MOD | MPEG-2 Video | MPEG-1/2 Video (mpgv) |
| .MTS | Unknown codec | MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264) |

Videos I have that frame forward and backward without any issue are:

| File Extension | QMediaPlayer | VLC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| .MP4 | H.264 Video | MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1) |
| .mp4 | MPEG-4 part 2 Video (M4S2) | MPEF-4 Video (mpv4) (h264) |

Is there a solution so that my script can I can frame forward and backward correctly?  Here is my method that frames forward within my within my video player class.

```
def frame_forward(self):
    if self.player.state() == QMediaPlayer.PausedState:
        now = self.player.position()
        self.player.setPosition(now + self.msecs)
        self.player.play()
        self.player.pause()
```

Comment: Not all video formats support frame-by-frame backwards (actually, most don't, due to the way compression works). The issue shouldn't exist when going forward, in theory, but that depends on the way the codec *and* player API is actually implemented. In both cases, I'm afraid that there's not a direct solution (especially, not one involving the play/pause trick even for forward frame by frame), and you might need to implement some level of internal buffering, which obviously would affect performance since it would be partially done on the python abstraction level.

Comment: Hmm.  This doesn't sound good.  I first wrote the player using OpenCV and it worked great  I wasn't buffering the frame capture.  I guess forward and backward framing worked fine because OpenCV converts each frame to a Numpy array.  But the OpenCV player doesn't process 4K videos within the seconds/frame, so it runs slowly.  QMediaPlayer can play 4K videos without any problem.  Any ideas on another solution?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure, 4k playback is quite demanding, and using python probably is not a good solution anyway due to its nature. Reading your other question, a big bottleneck could be the passages from QImage to the final QLabel, it's not really an OpenCV problem. The only solution I could think of would be to avoid resizing and setting the pixmap on the label, and use a QGraphicsPixmapItem on a QGraphicsScene, which will leave *almost* all scaling/conversion on the C++ side. But that's just a hunch, I would only try it as an experiment, but without putting too much hope.

Comment: Also, have a look at [QVideoProbe](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html). Maybe you can create a thread safe caching, and switch between standard QMediaPlayer playback and cache viewing when you need frame by frame playback.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try both over the weekend and report back.  I really appreciate the ideas.